# How to configure cherry-pick branch name?

Tags: gitlab, cherry-pick

When we are creating cherry-pick by [built-in function of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/cherry_pick_changes.html) on merged MR, it gets name like `cherry-pick-c2deb506`.
How to configure that name?  I can't find this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the cherry-pick branch name is not customizable through the GitLab interface.

You can follow relevant issues in the Gitlab bug-tracker:

- [[Feature] Name Cherry Pick Branch](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17462)
- [Confusing Cherry Pick Branch Name](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18825)